# VS 2010 Search is slow

Tags: visual-studio-2010

My search in VS2010 is taking really long, any way to speed it up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the best ways to speed it up revolve around targeting your search:

- "Match Case" - If you know the casing, it is one of the most significant ways to speed up your search.
- "Whole Word" - It uses the word boundaries to limit the searches.  If you are sure of the whole word, use this option.
- File Types - Limit the file types that you are searching on.  You probably know what you are searching for, in regards to what type of file you are expecting in return.

If you are using search functionality a lot to find class names, or implementations/definitions, I would recommend using a tool more like ReSharper, instead of searching, as well.

**EDIT** - Also, I never use "Find Next" if searching an entire solution, unless I am looking for an excuse to take a break.  "Find All" is much more attractive, to me, since it seems to perform better on large projects.

Comment: +1, don't search an entire solution if possible, I had tons of generated XML files that were being parsed.